# strtotime() doesn't recognize german shortform of date (dd.mm.YY)

Tags: php, date, timestamp

I have much data with several timestamps and I just recognized that some are in "dd.mm.YYYY" which works very well with `date("Y-m-d", strtotime($input));` but some are in "dd.mm.YY" and this does not work anymore - it always returns the current date.

My problem is that my data is too huge to fix this problem manually by editting. Is there any way to get the `YYYY-mm-dd` out of `mm.dd.YY` ?

Comment: could you give some example dates, which do not work?

Comment: `20.02.71` Feb 20 1971

Comment: `if (strlen($input) == 8) { $input = substr($input, 0, 6) . '19' . substr($input, -2); }`

Comment: @AbraCadaver That date, as well as all of the others I have tried, works fine for me. `var_dump(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("20.02.71")));` outputs `string(10) "1971-02-20"`.

Comment: @Phil What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @EdCottrell: Yeah, mistake.  Try `'20.02.01'`

Comment: Interestingly, if you do this one though: `echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("20.02.10"));` you get `2016-02-11`

Comment: One thing which does not work is `09.09.09` or `03.10.09` - and I use PHP 5.6.11

Comment: @AbraCadaver Hmm. The problem seems to be that the date is ambiguous.

Comment: @Henders That's exactly the behaviour I recognized - it can't convert the given date so it return the current

Answer (score 2):

Here you go...

```
$date = "20.02.71"; // sample date... (common German format)
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.y', $date);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

will result in:

> 1971-02-20

Create a DateTime object, then format it to anything you want...

Answer (score 0):

Well you can replace the `.` by `-`, you could do something like the following:

```
$date = str_replace(".", "-", "mm.dd.YY")
```

This would return

```
mm-dd-YY
```

You could use [date_parse_from_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php) which would convert any formate into the formate you specify.

```
date_parse_from_format("y-m-d", $date);
```

It returns an array with very useful information like month, year etc.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to use `date_parse_from_format("Y-m-d", $date);` not `YYYY-mm-dd` because the format parameter expects a format accepted by createFromFormat()?

Comment: @Henders yes indeed. Well spotted